# Pywin32 working with excel application, how to save as the file in other location than default?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

Hello, I have a task of reading .xlsx file with charts and images and editing some cells. As I was working with Charts I chose Pywin32 package for python.

So my problem is that when I read the template from a particular folder and save it in another (not in My documents) folder. Excel gives me an error message.

However when I dont provide a path and let excel save it in the default location('My documents') the program runs without any errors.

eg

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\myfiles\excel\workbook2.xlsx')
# read write some value
wb.SaveAs('add_a_worksheet.xlsx')
excel.Application.Quit()
```

this works but when a provide a path name for save as function (check below), I receive an error message:

> wb.SaveAs('C:\User....\add_a_worksheet.xlsx')

kindly help, thanks and best regards

The error that I get is:

> pywintypes.com_error:
>
> (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Office Excel',
>   u"Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file 'C:\8CBD2000'. There
>   are several possible reasons:\n\n\u2022 The file name or path does not
>   exist.\n\u2022 The file is being used by another program.\n\u2022 The
>   workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open
>   workbook.", u'C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Office\Office12\1033\XLMAIN11.CHM', 0, -2146827284), None)

Comment: very likely raw string issue, use raw prefix as in the input : `wb.SaveAs(r'C:\User\....\add_a_worksheet.xlsx')`

Comment: Thanks a lot  Jean-François Fabre, that was exactly the issue. I am new to coding. Thanks again .